# How does a request cancellation token actually get marked for cancellation?

Tags: c#, .net, cancellation

I'm looking for some more information on what actually causes `IsCancellationRequested` to become set for a [cancellation token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-6.0).

I see plenty of articles and videos stating to just throw the token in a `httpClient.PostAsync()` call and then we can check the property of `IsCancellationRequested` on the token that we pass in and do our cancellation processing if it's requested. I also see that we can use the token source to call cancel for it as well.

My confusion here is around me sending a request to an endpoint that I own and what triggers the `IsCancellationRequested` property to become set as true on my response. Will this become set as true on any exception thrown? And is this only possible to set as true on an exception being thrown? I don't full understand the role the server has in requesting a cancellation.

Comment: The CancellationToken mechanics are: When you call CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() the IsCancellationRequested property is set on the associated token. When you call HttpClient.PostAsync with a token and call Cancel on the source HttpClient aborts it’s request because it either checked if the IsCancellationRequested property is set or because it has subscribed to the token and got notified it was cancelled. If with server endpoint you mean an ASP.NET (Core) controller that it’s token is cancelled by the pipeline when it sees that the connection was aborted.

Comment: @ckuri so if I'm understanding this correctly, the purpose of the token is to have the requester abort the request based on something on the requesters side? it has nothing to do with something happening on the server side?

Comment: For ASP.NET (Core) you can also configure a timeout on the server side to limit how long a server action should take.  If I recall correctly, this would also set the server token when the time limit elapsed. Coming back to your initial question, an exception wouldn’t set the token.